# Shiny R - How to read folder content

Tags: r, shiny

I would like make a custom R script available by modifying it to run as a ShinyApp. The current script runs over all XML files present in the working directory and creates statistics and graphs.

In my script I use this line to read the relevant files from the working directory into R:

```
 filelist$file <- list.files(".", pattern = ".xml")
```

However, ShinyApp doesn't provide such a function (only file.input for single or multiple files), and solutions using choose.dir are limited to Windows systems, but I would like to be OS independent. It would be great if someone can point me to the right steps to get this function implemented so it can run on a ShinyApp in a browser.

Comment: Does the app need to search for new files as it is being run? Or will just once on startup work?

Comment: It though of an action button that opens a dialog to navigate to the local folder containing the files, which are then to be listed and uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing is probably:

```
fileInput('uploadfile', '', multiple=TRUE, accept = c(".xlm"))
```

The user would select all files in the directory (e.g., using ctrl-A or cmd-A) but only the .xlm files would be picked.